# Google Chrome not starting, hangs, won't bring into foreground

Tags: windows, google-chrome

All of sudden Chrome stops working properly. Whenever launched, the chrome does not appear in foreground but the task manager (windows 8.1) shows chrome processes. I've tried to reinstall the chrome (cleared all chrome-related folder in the local data folder before reinstallation) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, some part of a user profile was damaged.
Here are the steps to check and fix:

- press `Win+R`, this opens "Run" window.
- paste `%localappdata%\Google` to there, run. This opens folder with google-sw-related files for current user.
- rename Chrome folder to, say, Chrome-old
- install/start Chrome, it should start fresh
- if there is something of value left in broken profile, bookmarks, whatnot, you could later try to move to the newly created clean profile.

Workaround: one could use **Google Chrome Portable** from [**Portable Apps**](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) which would hold user profile in a subfolder, which could be used instead or help ruling-out profile or access-rights troubles.

Comment: I cleared all chrome-related folder in the local data folder before reinstallation. still not solve the problem

Comment: i suggest you put this important detail in the question, narrows solutions space, improves searchability